Cannot update a component X while rendering a different component Y
I have no idea why i get this error in next js 14, because i think my code looks fine. I have checked another file, but it seems the resource of error because of this file. And the error only comes when i click add form for the first time, for the second time and third time the error doesn't come again.
++ Btw i have tried also using Controller but the issue still persist.


import {PlusIcon,
    Trash
} from 'lucide-react';
import {
    useState
} from 'react';
import {
    useFieldArray,
    useFormContext
} from 'react-hook-form';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import {
    Button
} from '@/components/shadcnui/button';

import {
    type ProductFormType
} from '../form';
import {
    SelectCreateableInput
} from '@/components/shared-component/atom/Select/Select';

export function ProductVariationSection() {
    const form = useFormContext < ProductFormType > ();

    const {
        fields,
        append
    } = useFieldArray({
        name: 'variationName',
        control: form.control,
    });

    // State untuk menyimpan jumlah variationName yang akan ditampilkan
    const [variationNumber, setVariationNumber] = useState(1);

    const {
        watch,
        register
    } = form;

    const variationName = watch('variationName');
    const variationType = watch('variationType');

    const handleAddNewVariationName = (
        e: React.MouseEvent < HTMLButtonElement >
    ) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        append({
            value: '',
            label: ''
        });
    };

    return ( <
            div className = "flex flex-col gap-3" > {
                fields.map((field, index) => ( <
                        div className = "grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 items-start"
                        key = {
                            field.id
                        } >
                        <
                        Button variant = "default"
                        type = "button"
                        size = "icon"
                        className = "mt-6"
                        onClick = {
                            handleAddNewVariationName
                        } >
                        <
                        PlusIcon className = "h-5 w-5" / >
                        <
                        /Button> < /
                        div >
                    );
                }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



Error log 1
Error log 2
Error log 3
